# How should I choose Keras parameters for grid exploration?

Tags: keras, lstm, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I am trying to train a neural network to efficiently explore a grid to locate an object using [Keras](https://keras.io/) and [Keras-RL](https://github.com/matthiasplappert/keras-rl). Every "step", the agent chooses a direction to explore by choosing a number from `0` to `8`, where each corresponds to a cardinal or intermediate direction.

(Using reinforcement learning for this simple task is clearly not the best choice, as a simple algorithm could easily scan back and forth to achieve the goal. However, this serves more as a "tech demo" and challenge to myself.)

The following diagram represents all possible choices. `0` indicates northwest, `1` indicates north, `2` indicates northeast, etc. Note that `4` represents the choice to stay stationary.

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
```

The observation function returns the explored states of tiles within a certain radius of "vision" (`.flatten()`ed), and the reward function simply returns the number of unexplored grid tiles within this radius.

In the following diagram, which uses a radius of `2`, `█` represents an explored tile, `■` represents a tile within the radius of vision, `o` represents the explorer, `x` represents the desired object, and  represents an entirely unexplored tile.

```
+--------+
|████████|
|██■■■█  |
|██■o■   |
|  ■■■   |
|       x|
+--------+
```

I am using the following model. During my experimentation, I typically use a 20x20 grid, with varying numbers of 16-node `Dense` layers (arbitrarily chosen).

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(2, input_shape=(1,) + observation_shape))
# observation_shape is the number of tiles being returned by observation

for _ in range(nb_dense):
    model.add(Dense(dense_output))
# nb_dense and dense_output are varied manually, for testing purposes

model.add(Dense(nb_actions))  # output shape = 9 (number of directions)
model.add(Activation("linear"))
print(model.summary())

memory = SequentialMemory(limit=50000, window_length=1)
policy = EpsGreedyQPolicy(eps=.1)
dqn = DQNAgent(
    model=model,
    nb_actions=nb_actions,
    memory=memory,
    nb_steps_warmup=10,
    target_model_update=1e-2,
    policy=policy
)
dqn.compile(Adam(lr=1e-3), metrics=['mae'])

dqn.fit(env, nb_steps=50000, visualize=False, verbose=2)

dqn.test(env, nb_episodes=5, visualize=True)
```

Unfortunately, even after much testing, the agent is still unable to find the object within any stretch of a reasonable amount of time, if at all.

- Is there something inherently wrong with my layer setup? (Should I use more/less `Dense`, `LSTM`, etc.?)
- Are my `SequentialMemory`, `EpsGreedyQPolicy`, `DQNAgent`, or`.compile()` values non-ideal for the situation?
- Is exploration itself too complex of a problem for such a simple network to solve?

In general, how could I improve the network so that it would actually succeed in exploration, finding the object in a relatively short amount of time regardless of its placement?